# MouseDown Event is not being called from the correct instance of a class

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom class called PointsView, it is a subclass of SCNView.

```
@interface PointsView : SCNView <SCNSceneRendererDelegate>
```

I have initialised an object of PointsView in my ViewController class, in the method viewDidLoad.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    pointsView = [[PointsView alloc] initView:sceneView withScene:pointsScene];
}
```

This initialises pointsView with a SCNView and a SCNScene, both are created in ViewController and are linked to my storyboard. Attributes for the SCNView and SCNScene are set in the PointsView class.

```
@implementation PointsView

- (id)initView:(SCNView *)ptsView withScene:(SCNScene *)curScene {
    self = [super init];

    mySCNView = ptsView;
    currentScene = curScene;

    mySCNView.delegate = self;

    mySCNView.scene = currentScene;
    mySCNView.allowsCameraControl = NO;
    mySCNView.jitteringEnabled = YES;
    mySCNView.showsStatistics = NO;
    mySCNView.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor];

    cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0.4, 6);
    cameraNode.transform = CATransform3DRotate(cameraNode.transform, -M_PI/7.0, 0, 0, 0);
    cameraNode.orientation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, 0);
    cameraNode.camera.yFov = 40.0;
    cameraNode.camera.xFov = 0;
    cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.5;

    [currentScene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];

    SCNLight *spotLight = [SCNLight light];
    spotLight.type = SCNLightTypeSpot;
    spotLight.color = [NSColor blackColor];
    SCNNode *spotLightNode = [SCNNode node];
    spotLightNode.light = spotLight;
    spotLightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-2, 1, 0);

    [cameraNode addChildNode:spotLightNode];

    return self;
}
```

I have a rightMouseDown event in the the PointsView class, the problem is when that method is called it is being called from an instance of PointsView that is different from the one that was initialised in ViewController, for example; location in memory after initialisation was 0x100b032a0, and when rightMouseDown is called, location in memory was 0x100908630. Which tells me it is not the same instance.

```
- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    SCNHitTestResult *result = [self hitTestResultForEvent:theEvent];
}
```

I have no idea why another instance is being used for the rightMouseDown event. I need to be using the one that was initialised in ViewController. Am I doing anything wrong? Or is there something I have missed? Help would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone needs anymore information, please ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. I used the firstResponder attribute from NSEvent, which I had set to the ViewController. From there I could access my already initialised PointsView class.